# How to calculate similarities between tags?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've started to solve some exercises from the book Programming Collective Intelligence in Python. The question two is:
Using the del.icio.us API, create a dataset of tags and items. Use this to calculate     similarity between tags and see if you can find any that are almost identical. Find some items that could have been tagged “programming” but were not.

So far I created a dictionary that I parsed data from a text file called tags.txt.

```
def asd():
d = dict()
for line in open("tags.txt"):
    if len(line.strip().split("\t")) == 23:
        url, number_of_saves, data_of_first_save, tag1, tagCount1, tag2, tagCount2, tag3, tagCount3, tag4, tagCount4, tag5,tagCount5,\
        tag6, tagCount6, tag7, tagCount7, tag8, tagCount8, tag9, tagCount9, tag10, tagCount10 = line.strip().split("\t")
        tags = [tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9,tag10]
        tagCounts = [tagCount1,tagCount2,tagCount3,tagCount4,tagCount5,tagCount6,tagCount7,tagCount8,tagCount9,tagCount10]
        d.setdefault(url, {})
        for index, tag in enumerate(tags):
            d[url][tag] = tagCounts[index]
return d
```

My question is how can I find similarities between tags using this dictionary?

Comment: There are many ways to tackle this, for example see how many tags two url's have in common.

Comment: If you're looking for strictly similarity based on a tag's string, you may want to investigate the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), as it's the typical first step for calculating string similarity.

Comment: Do you have criteria for what you consider similar? Semantically similar (`scripting`, `programming`)? Semantically dissimilar yet orthographically similar (`CS` `CSS`)?

Comment: To evaluate similarity of two string, use the ``difflib`` module. You may be interested by the eample you wil find in one of my answers: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18873117/551449)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Use this to calculate similarity between tags"
>
> "almost identical"

Consider [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance): "*Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences*".