# How to inverse lemmatization process given a lemma and a token?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

Generally, in natural language processing, we want to get the lemma of a token.

For example, we can map 'eaten' to 'eat' using wordnet lemmatization.

**Is there any tools in python that can inverse lemma to a certain form?**

For example, we map 'go' to 'gone' given target form 'eaten'.

PS: Someone mentions we have to store such mappings.
[How to un-stem a word in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266502/how-to-un-stem-a-word-in-python)

Comment: POS information can also be used to gain certain form of lemma.

Comment: How would you know if you map "go" to "gone" or "goes" or "went" ...etc Lemmatization allows for better performance, but it is a tradeoff where you lose some information. If needs be, you'd need to conserve a lemma with a list of possible variation (possibly with their position if you want to recreate a text from those "augmented lemmas")

Comment: @Adonis I would add additional variables as constraints or targets. 
For example,
def inverse_lemma(**args).
'gone' = inverse_lemma(lemma='go', target_form='eaten', target_pos='VBN').
Something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning a base form such as a lemma into a situation-appropriate form is called [realization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_%28linguistics%29) (or "surface realization"). Example from Wikipedia:

```
NPPhraseSpec subject = nlgFactory.createNounPhrase("the", "woman");
subject.setPlural(true);
SPhraseSpec sentence = nlgFactory.createClause(subject, "smoke");
sentence.setFeature(Feature.NEGATED, true);
System.out.println(realiser.realiseSentence(sentence));
// output: "The women do not smoke."
```

Libraries for this are not as frequently used as lemmatizers, which generally means you have fewer options and are less likely to find a well developed library. The Wikipedia example is in Java because the most popular library supporting this is [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg).

A quick search found [pynlg](https://github.com/mapado/pynlg), though it doesn't seem actively maintained. Alternately you can use SimpleNLG via an HTTP JSON interface provided by the Python library [nlgserv](https://github.com/mnestis/nlgserv).

Comment: Thanks @polm23! I'll have a try.