# Abbreviation similarity between strings

Tags: python, similarity, edit-distance, jaro-winkler

I have a use case in my project where I need to compare a `key`-string with a lot many strings for similarity. If this value is greater than a certain threshold, I consider those strings "similar" to my `key` and based on that list, I do some further calculations / processing.

I have been exploring fuzzy matching string similarity stuff, which use `edit distance` based algorithms like "levenshtein, jaro and jaro-winkler" similarities.

Although they work fine, I want to have a higher similarity score if one string is "abbreviation" of another. Is there any algorithm/ implementation I can use for this.

Note:

```
language: python3 
packages explored: fuzzywuzzy, jaro-winkler
```

Example:

```
using jaro_winkler similarity:

>>> jaro.jaro_winkler_metric("wtw", "willis tower watson")
0.7473684210526316
>>> jaro.jaro_winkler_metric("wtw", "willistowerwatson")
0.7529411764705883

using levenshtein similarity:

>>> fuzz.ratio("wtw", "willis tower watson")
27
>>> fuzz.ratio("wtw", "willistowerwatson")
30
>>> fuzz.partial_ratio("wtw", "willistowerwatson")
67
>>> fuzz.QRatio("wtw", "willistowerwatson")
30
```

In these kind of cases, I want score to be higher (>90%) if possible. I'm ok with few false positives as well, as they won't cause too much issue with my further calculations. But if we match s1 and s2 such that s1 is fully contained in s2 (or vice versa), their similarity score should be much higher.

### Edit: Further Examples for my Use-Case

For me, spaces are redundant. That means, `wtw` is considered abbreviation for "willistowerwatson" and "willis tower watson" alike.

Also, `stove` is a valid abbreviation for "STack OVErflow" or "STandardOVErview"

A simple algo would be to start with 1st char of smaller string and see if it is present in the larger one. Then check for 2nd char and so on until the condition satisfies that 1st string is fully contained in 2nd string. This is a 100% match for me.

Further examples like `wtwx` to "willistowerwatson" could give a score of, say 80% (this can be based on some edit distance logic). Even if I can find a package which gives either `True` or `False` for abbreviation similarity would also be helpful.

Comment: Check the following answer at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871706/check-if-two-words-are-related-to-each-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive algorithm, similar to sequence alignment. Just don't give penalty for shifts (as they are expected in abbreviations) but give one for mismatch in first characters.

This one should work, for example:

```
def abbreviation(abr,word,penalty=1):
    if len(abr)==0:
        return 0
    elif len(word)==0:
        return penalty*len(abr)*-1
    elif abr[0] == word[0]:
        if len(abr)>1:
            return 1 + max(abbreviation(abr[1:],word[1:]),
                           abbreviation(abr[2:],word[1:])-penalty)
        else:
            return 1 + abbreviation(abr[1:],word[1:])
    else:
        return abbreviation(abr,word[1:])

def compute_match(abbr,word,penalty=1):
    score = abbreviation(abbr.lower(),
                         word.lower(),
                         penalty)
    if abbr[0].lower() != word[0].lower(): score-=penalty
    
    score = score/len(abbr)

    return score


print(compute_match("wtw", "willis tower watson"))
print(compute_match("wtwo", "willis tower watson"))
print(compute_match("stove", "Stackoverflow"))
print(compute_match("tov", "Stackoverflow"))
print(compute_match("wtwx", "willis tower watson"))
```

The output is:

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
0.6666666666666666
0.5
```

Indicating that `wtw` and `wtwo` are perfectly valid abbreviations for `willistowerwatson`, that `stove` is a valid abbreviation of `Stackoverflow` but not `tov`, which has the wrong first character.
And `wtwx` is only partially valid abbreviation for `willistowerwatson` beacuse it ends with a character that does not occur in the full name.

Comment: Hi @Martin, this is a great answer. I will be awarding the bounty to this as its the last day as well. This probably solves my use case behaviourally, I'll just have to check on its performance in the large dataset that I have.
However, as for the output scores, this is probably exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To detect abbrevioations in string, you can still using `fuzzywuzzy` module with the `process()` function:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

s1 = ["willis tower watson", "stack overflow", "willistowerwatson", "international business machines"]
s2 = ['wtw', "so", "wtw", "ibz"]

queries = [''.join([i[0] for i in j.split()]) for j in s1]

for query, company in zip(queries, s1):
    print(company, '-', process.extractOne(query, s2, scorer=fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio))
```

**Output:**

```
willis tower watson - ('wtw', 100)
stack overflow - ('so', 100)
willistowerwatson - ('wtw', 100)
international business machines - ('ibz', 67)
```

Comment: For me, `fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio("wtw", "willistowerwatson")` gives score of 67 and `fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio("wtw", "willis tower watson")` gives 33. What is it that we are doing different here?

Comment: @vish4071 You need a different way of processing the string to detect the abbreviation, depending on if it has spaces or not.

Comment: Spaces are redundant here. I would consider "wtw" to be abbreviation of "willistowerwatson" and "willis tower watson" alike. Also, in your example, 3rd record matches "wtw" with "willistowerwatson" with score of 100?!!

Comment: @vish4071 Yes, but how would you make a set of steps to detect "wtw" to be abbreviation of "willistowerwatson" and "willis tower watson" at the same time?

Comment: A simple algo would be to start with 1st char of smaller string and see if it is there in larger one. Then check for 2nd char and so on until I'm able to satisfy the condition that 1st string is fully contained in 2nd string. This is a 100% match for me.

Comment: Another example to consider could be: `stove` is a valid abbreviation for "stack overflow". I hope this example would clear my use case further